# How to compute the exponential of this given matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have a problem and can't find any solution. I have the matrix $A= \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 2 \pi \\ -2 \pi & 0 \\ \end{bmatrix}$ and I must compute the matrix $e^A$.

I remeber that there was several cases, to be exact 3, about how to calculate this matrix depending on the eigenvalue and eigenvectors, but I can't find them. Can somebody help?

Comment: Can you find the eigenvalues and eigenvectors?

Comment: Hint: The eigenvalues are imaginary. Also, while often you'd need to find the eigenvectors, in this case you magically don't.

Comment: Hint: Since this is a conformal matrix, which behaves like a complex number, you can take a short cut if you can identify that number.

Answer (score 2):

You can straightforwardly write $A$ as $2 \pi B$ with $B$ the matrix
\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ -1 & 0 \\ \end{bmatrix}
then make use that $B^2 = -I$, $B^3 = -B$, $B^4 = I$, $B^5 = B$ *etc*, then substitute into the expansion for $e^A = I + \frac{1}{1!}A + \frac{1}{2!}A^2 + .... $ and collect terms in $I$ and $B$.

Answer (score 2):

Note that $A=PDP^{-1}$ where
\begin{align*}
D &=
\left[\begin{array}{rr}
-2 i \, \pi & 0 \\
 0 & 2 i \, \pi
\end{array}\right] & 
P &=
\left[\begin{array}{rr}
1 & 1 \\
-i & i
\end{array}\right]
\end{align*}
Hence
\begin{align*}
\exp(A)
&= P\exp(D)P^{-1} \\
&= P 
\left[\begin{array}{rr}
e^{-2i\,\pi} & 0 \\
0 & e^{2i\,\pi}
\end{array}\right]
P^{-1} \\
&=
P
\left[\begin{array}{rr}
1&0\\0&1
\end{array}\right] P^{-1} \\
&=
PIP^{-1} \\
&=PP^{-1} \\
&= I
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

Notice first that $\pmatrix{0& 1\\ -1 & 0}$ appears very similar (isomorphic) to the complex number $i$ in every possible way. With this in mind, what you have is actually $e^{2\pi i}$ which is 1! Now, apply the map $a + bi \mapsto \pmatrix{a & b \\ -b & a}$ which is the inverse of the original transformation from matrices to the complex numbers.